# Google tag manager - multiple tags detected, is this correct?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I've just replaced my google analytics tag with a Google Tag manager installation integrated into GA. When I inspect my page with Google Tag assistant I see the installation of tag manager and 2 GA tags, is this correct?

[image]

I only have 1 GA property setup, is there a reason I'm seeing a second one?

Comment: You might still have on-page tracking on your site. Check your page source to see if you see any other GA tracking snippet.

Answer (score 0):

There are many third-party widgets or plugins such as comment boxes or forms that use Google Analytics to track user interaction with their plugin. Considering the fact that the two Google Analytics Id's are from different accounts, this seems like a plausible reason.

To check this, copy the GA Id in question, view the page source, and search, (cmd+F) for the Id in the code. If this is the reason, the GA code will likely be embedded with the widget's code.